# I need help with functions, specifically the ones including sin, cos, and tan

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I’m still new with functions so I’m not the best at using them. I got a question which really confuses me:

> If $\sin(t)=0.9$, calculate $\sin(\pi-t)$.

The answer to this was $0.9$ and I don’t know how it was obtained. I need an explanation of how this works.

Comment: $\sin (\pi - t) = \sin t$ is an identity, and you can obtain it from the geometric definition of the sine function.

Comment: It is a basic property of the sine function, as defined from the trigonometric circle.

Comment: What is the sine function?

Comment: It is a common trigonometric function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine

Comment: @Somxr, look at this [property](https://socratic.org/questions/does-sin-pi-x-sin-x) (if you are familiar with sine difference formula which is $\sin(A - B) = \sin(A)  \cos(B) - \cos(A)  \sin(B)$)